# How do I toggle the Solution Pad in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: macos, xamarin

This may be an extremely ridiculous question, but I cross develop applications on Mac and Windows, and my Xamarin install on Windows popped up w/ the Solution Pad automatically on my projects, but the Mac install didn't. I've been able to develop fine w/out the Solution Pad on my Mac, but it would be tremendously advantageous to my development and time to have the Solution Pad available. I've also done some thorough Googling for the subject but haven't been able to find an answer, even in the Xamarin documentation. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the menu

```
View --> Pads --> Solution
```